# Not able to run my app on Simulator which using Agora iOS SDK

Tags: ios, agora.io, apple-m1

I am building an iOS application which is using Agora iOS SDK pod 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS' version 3.3.2

When I run application using real device it is working fine. But when I build application using simulator it gives an error:

> Framework not found AgoraAIDenoiseExtension

My laptop has Apple M1 chip and OS Big Sur version 11.2

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding AgoraAIDenoiseExtension.xcframework file in Frameworks and Libraries

**Steps to follow:**

1. Select your project
2. Go to General Tab
3. Go to Frameworks and Libraries and click on + button.
4. Add respective framework files
5. Clean and Run your project

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've solved it with a temporary fix Dalijeet, but another solution would be to use swift package manager here:

https://github.com/AgoraIO/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS